# How do I put align elements into fixed columns?

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

I want an "align" equation in one column and a text table in the other column. In LaTeX, it seems that "tables" and "columns" are separate but overlapping mechanisms.

In LaTeX, "columns" seem to be things that auto-flow. I want columns where I manually specify what goes in each column. I guess this is done with "tables" and table columns? However, inside of a table I can't use many constructs such as `\[ \]` or `align` elements.  Is there any solution to this?

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{align*}
        y = b + \sum\limits_i x_i w_i
    \end{align*}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You need `p{<length>}` column and also an extra pair of braces around the `align*` to hide the alignment  `&`s

Comment: Something like this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|m{.4\linewidth}|c|}
    \hline
    {\begin{align*}
        y &= b + \sum_i x_i w_i \\
            &=c 
    \end{align*}}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{ll}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to typsete an `align` or a displayed equation using `\[...\]` inside a column, you need a paragraph type column; either `p{<length>}` or `m{<length>}` (the latter provided by [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package).

However, in your example case, I'd suggest you to use `aligned` instead of `align*` and to suppress the vertical rules and use the features provided by the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.

Three versions of your table: the first one, without major modifications (except for the use of `aligned`); the second one, introducing some more "air" bettern horizontal rules and content through `\arraystretch`, and the third one, using `booktabs` and no vertical rules.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{$}c<{$}|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{aligned}
        y &= b + \sum\limits_i x_i w_i \\
           &= c.
    \end{aligned}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
\begin{longtable}{|>{$}c<{$}|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{aligned}
        y &= b + \sum\limits_i x_i w_i \\
           &= c.
    \end{aligned}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
}

\begin{longtable}{>{$}c<{$} c}
    \toprule
    \begin{aligned}
        y &= b + \sum\limits_i x_i w_i \\
           &= c.
    \end{aligned}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps, depending on your actual intent, it would also be a good idea to suppress the padding at the beginning and ending of the inner `tabular`:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    a & b \\
    a & b \\
\end{tabular}
```